# Cannot find module './routes/viewInprogressDetails' ( node app with docker )

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, node-modules, docker-image

I have created docker image for the node application, which is working fine when i run before creating docker image.

my docker file contains:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node app.js
EXPOSE 3000
```

Step 1:

```
$ docker build -t myapp .
```

Step 2:

```
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

when i run the above command Im facing below error:

$ docker run -p 3000:3000 kpnv7

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './routes/viewInprogressDetails'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:16:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

Not sure where im doing wrong, same application running fine when i give node app.js without errors :(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you say "same application running fine when i give node app.js without errors".. where did you run it successfully? on the host machine or exec bash into container and run node app.js? Also, consider moving CMD line to the end of your Dockerfile

Comment: It is running successfully on the terminal when we run the node app.